# Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) FRAPO

Tags: rstudio

install.packages("FRAPO")

install.packages("quantmod")

library(FRAPO)

library(quantmod)

startDate <- "2006-01-01"

endDate <- "2015-12-31"

## Load input data:----

```
symbols = c("XLF", "XLP", "XLE", "XLY", "XLV", "XLI", "XLB", "XLK", "XLU")

getSymbols(symbols, src="yahoo", from=startDate, to=endDate)

price.data<-cbind(XLY[,6],XLP[,6],XLE[,6],XLF[,6],XLV[,6],XLI[,6],XLB[,6],XLK[,6], XLU[,6])

colnames(price.data)<-c("Consumer Discretionary", "Consumer Staples", "Energy",
                        "Financial", "Health Care", "Industrial", "Materials",
                        "Technology", "Utilities")

names<-c("Consumer Discretionary", "Consumer Staples", "Energy",
         "Financial", "Health Care", "Industrial", "Materials",
         "Technology", "Utilities")

mcdd<-PMinCDaR(price.data, alpha = 0.95, softBudget = FALSE)
round(mcdd@weights, digits=8)
```

And I get :

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘returnseries’ for signature ‘"xts"’
```

I want to use the S&P 500 time series to check the (PMinCDaR )Portfolio optimization for minimum conditional drawdown at risk for the S&P500. But when I tried to use PMinCDaR I get the error:  in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘returnseries’ for signature ‘"xts"’

Comment: try to provide some explanation to get more help.

Comment: I want to use the S&P 500 time series to check the (PMinCDaR )Portfolio optimization for minimum conditional drawdown at risk for the S&P500. But when I tried to use PMinCDaR I get the error:  in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘returnseries’ for signature ‘"xts"’